# What is the difference between two image pixels in term of light?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, physics

[Light Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_field) captures the scene from slightly different points. This means I would have two images of the same scene with a slight shift, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

Assuming the red squares in the images above are pixels. I know that the spatial difference between those two pixels is a shift. Nevertheless, what other information do these two pixels give us in terms of scene radiance? I mean is there a way to find (or compute) the difference in image irradiance values between those two points?

Comment: Try visualizing the images in the luminance channel after converting them to CIELAB color space..

Answer (score 0):

Look for color space representations other than RGB. Some of them have explicit channel(s) carrying luminance information of a pixel.

A varaiant of the same idea is to convert to a Black and White image and examine the pixel values.